# How to construct JSON dynamically from array list of elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
I have a list of elements in an array: empIds: [38670, 38671, 38672, 38673]

I am trying to build a JSON that holds all these array elements in the payload:

    {
    
     "members": [
        {
            "EmployeeId": "38670"
        },
        {
            "EmployeeId": "38671"
        },
        {
            "EmployeeId": "38672"
        },
        {
            "EmployeeId": "38673"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I wasn't completely sure as I am trying to get my head around. Below is my incomplete implementation:
`

```
     let parts = [];
                for(i=0;i<memberInternalIds.length; i++){
                    if(memberInternalIds.length == 1){
                        parts ={participantId: memberInternalIds[0]}          
                    } else {
                        parts ={participantId: memberInternalIds[i]}  
                    }
                }
```

`

Not sure how to dynamically create JSON structure with followed by comma-separated key/values.

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and return an array of objects using the iterated element as the `employeeId` value. Then [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it to get JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const empIds = [38670, 38671, 38672, 38673];

let payload = { members: empIds.map(id => ({"EmployeeId": id})) };

// Convert the payload to a JSON string
const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(payload);

// Print the JSON string
console.log(jsonStr);
```

Comment: Why `var`  and not `const` ?

Comment: I moved your code into a runnable snippet so others can run and verify how it works